# constantly receives an error about flashplugin-installer

Tags: flash

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.1. From the day that which i have installed it, there has been an error message of the following type appears:

> **failure to download extra data files**
>
> the following packages requested additional data downloads after package information, > but the data could not be downloaded or could not be processed
>
> flashplugin-installer
>
> the download will be attempted agin latter, or you can try the download again now. Running this command requires an active internet connection.

Comment: did you cancel installation during downloading this package?

Comment: No i am not cancel installation during downloading this package. in fact i have downloaded and reinstalled flashplugin-installer three times.

Comment: open terminal <Ctrl>+<Alt>+<T> and try to type `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`.

Comment: i have already did this. after typing the command you have told me and then pressing enter the terminal window closed automatically after 1 or 2 minutes.

Comment: take a look this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/319284/283843

Answer (score 4):

`sudo rm /var/lib/update-notifier/user.d/data-downloads-failed`

fixed on 14.04

Answer (score 3):

Installing **adobe-flashplugin** instead is one way of avoiding this error:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Chromium/Getting-Partner-Flash

[What's the difference between flashplugin-installer and adobe-flashplugin?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49298/whats-the-difference-between-flashplugin-installer-and-adobe-flashplugin)

(came here looking for a solution to the same problem)